# Rich Text Box, cant set richtextbox1.RTF

Tags: richtextbox, rtf, richtext

I am trying to set the RTF property of a richTextBox as follows:

```
this.richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang5129{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl240\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22{\pict\pngblip\picw685\pich109\picwgoal685\pichgoal109" + imagestring + @"}\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\par}";
var rts = this.richTextBox1.Rtf;
```

when you debug the rts var has something different in it.

```
"{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang5129{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}\r\n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\sa200\\sl240\\slmult1\\f0\\fs17\\par\r\n}\r\n"
```

Which I am assuming is the defaults set up for RTB. Why can I not seem to set this Property? Is the RTB perhaps validating the rich text string?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not entering the format correctly.
I suggest pasting the image into the richtext box and then check its RTF property to see how it should be.